# How to prevent the quickfix window showing lslint errors on save?

Tags: neovim, debugging

Every time I save a file in neovim, quickfix window with all the errors is shown.

[image]

How do I prevent it from happening?

Reference: Here is my lsp config in my init.vim file:

```
  -- Setup lspconfig.
  -- see https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/issues/382#issuecomment-1166058387
  local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').update_capabilities(vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities())
  local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
  local navbuddy = require('nvim-navbuddy')
  local servers = { 'tsserver', 'eslint', 'bashls','jsonls','sumneko_lua' } 

  for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
      lspconfig[lsp].setup {
          capabilities = capabilities,
          flags = lsp_flags,
          on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
            navbuddy.attach(client, bufnr)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gv', function() 
                    vim.cmd([[
                        vsplit
                        ]])
                        vim.lsp.buf.definition()
            end, bufopts)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gl', vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
          end
      }
  end
```

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: This is not caused by your LSP set-up (at least not by the snippet you shared). You probably installed a plug-in that does this automatically

Comment: ah i see, i guess this is a weekend project for me, when the wife and kids are long asleep 

Comment: i remember this problem happened while i was experimenting with some plugins, good luck to me finding out which plugin that is now lol